# Rails access template of inclusion from partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a partial, how can I tell which template called it?

Ex:

```
# app/views/shared/_link_list.html.haml
%ul
  %li{ class: "#{template_of_inclusion}" }= link_to 'List item', 'blah'
```

I know I can pass it in as a local like `= render 'link_list', template_of_inclusion: …`, but I've already included this partial from several views, and I'd rather update it than go back and update all the other views.

Comment: It has been suggested to me that, in this case, the partial has knowledge of its context, which is an antipattern. I'd still love to know how to do it, though.